# Bootstrap - Sass install on Remote server sub-directory without command line access

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I've been struggling with this for a few days. Recently, our company discovered the existence of SASS, and we thought that going forward, it could be used to replace the standard php/css layout that we utilize to improve workflow in our update procedure.

However, due to the fact that we operate on a remote server for our staging server, and do not (currently) have access to command-line, I have yet to come up with an answer as to how to implement this.

In the bootstrap-sass, http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt, the readme.md file included states the four methods of installation, of which all of them require some command-line prompts.

Now, at least for wordpress sites, this is resolved using a SASSY theme and a plugin(albeit with stripped down functionality) I was wondering if it were possible to do something similar with bootstrap.

The plugin url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/

(I can't link what the plugin is based off of until 10 rep, its in the plugin description)

Would this work for bootstrap as well? Or is it specific to Wordpress? Or is there a newer method that will install it without access to command-line? Thanks for any input!

Comment: That plugin states that you can specify which directories to compile. So in short, yes. Maybe somebody that has used that plugin will chime in but it sounds like it should work as long as you specify the bootstrap sass files in the plugin's configuration.

Getting remote access to the server is the best solution so hopefully you guys can get that setup.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however, I'm looking to implement the functionality of the plugin for wordpress without wordpress installed. To have a basic bootstrap design Sassified without access to command line arguments. Sorry that I was not clear enough in OP.